# is winrt code better protected against reverse engineering?

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime

My application is being developed in silverlight. Plan to launch it later this year. I am worried against my xaps getting reverse-engineered. I do have a fare amount of intelligence in my wcf service but you cant put everything in the service. Now winrt is anothe option. Fact that both silverlight and winrt use xaml, it seems possible to move my client code to winrt but only if that code is protected against reverse engineering. Opinions?

Comment: +1. Sadly, as of now, I don't know any way of protecting my code from reverse-engineering either. Obfuscation only goes so far...

Comment: No, WinRT is a huge chunk of native code just like Win32 was.  Nobody wants or needs to reverse-engineer that.  Your Silverlight app is still IL.  Nobody is going to try to rev-eng it on a Win8 ARM pad, your Silverlight app won't work on it.  The best countermeasure against rev-eng is no different, before or after WinRT, you can write code a lot faster than anybody can or want to dissemble it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

http://JustinAngel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps

Comment: Excellent investigation. But does it still hold true with the latest Consumer Preview?

Comment: wow, thanks for detailed analysis Justin. Filip, I wanted to mark your answer also as a correct one as that makes sense too but SO wouldn't let me mark both as the answers. Thanks to both.

Comment: Phil, Yep. The location of files on the disk has changed, but everything is still factually accurate.

Answer (score 2):

There is little that can protect your code against reverse engineering. Running on server hides the code making it most secure, obfuscation still protects it quite well, but not completely and it has some other risks. **WinRT allows you to write native code, which is a bit harder to reverse engineer than .NET code, but only marginally**. On the other hand - if your application is written in non-minified javascript - you are basically shipping your source code and you don't even have a xap file to decompress - just look in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps and there is a folder for your app where all the files you see in Visual Studio are stored.

You can look at these options then and decide what would work best for you. Ultimately though - the choice between WinRT and Silverlight is a choice of platform - WinRT applications will only run on Windows 8 and (we can speculate) possibly on the next version of Windows Phone, which at least initially - limits your target audience. I have not heard of the option to sell Silverlight apps through Windows Store, unless you are targeting Windows Phone, where that is the only option (that and XNA - both being .NET based).

If your client-side code is indeed a unique intellectual property - you are better off protecting it with patents and copyright law than with obfuscation and compilation.